# How to have all parent classes in one grandparent class without gaining all attributes of grandparent class?

Tags: java, polymorphism, bluej

I am rather new to Java, rather only a week's worth of learning so I am still very inexperienced. I have spent a few days on polymorphism and know that I can extend a parent class to a child class, but I would like to know how to have a grandparent class have all the attributes of the parent classes. I have done a bit of research but haven't found what I was looking for. What I am working on is creating objects of clothing. I have one grandparent which is 'Clothing' three parents 'Upper_wear', 'Lower_wear', and 'Shoes' with many children such as 't-shirts', 'shorts' and 'sandals'. Currently what I have in the parents code is:

```
public class Upper_wear
{
    private String fabric;
    private int numb_zippers;
    private String draw_string;
    private int numb_pockets;
    private int size;
    private String color;
    private double length_sleeves;
    private int length_shirt;
    private String collar;
    private String hood;
    private int code;
    private double price;
    private String name;
    Upper_wear(String fabric,int numb_zippers,String draw_string,int numb_pockets,int size,String color, double length_sleeves, int length_shirt, String collar, String hood, int code, double price, String name){
        this.fabric = fabric;
        this.numb_zippers = numb_zippers;
        this.draw_string = draw_string;
        this.numb_pockets = numb_pockets;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.length_sleeves = length_sleeves;
        this.length_shirt = length_shirt;
        this.collar = collar;
        this.hood = hood;
        this.code = code;
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;

    }
    public String get_fabric(){
        return fabric;
    }
    public int get_numb_zippers(){
        return numb_zippers;
    }
    public String get_draw_string(){
        return draw_string;
    }
    public int get_numb_pockets(){
        return numb_pockets;
    }
    public int get_size(){
        return size;
    }
    public String get_color(){
        return color;
    }
    public double get_length_sleeves(){
        return length_sleeves;
    }
    public int get_length_shirt(){
        return length_shirt;
    }
    public String get_collar(){
        return collar;
    }
    public String get_hood(){
        return hood;
    }
    public int get_code(){
        return code;
    }
    public double get_price(){
        return price;
    }
    public String get_name(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

And for the children's code I have:

```
public class Jacket extends Upper_wear
{
    Jacket(String fabric,int numb_zippers,String draw_string,int numb_pockets,int size,String color, double length_sleeves, int length_shirt, String collar, String hood, int code, double price, String name){
        super(fabric, numb_zippers, draw_string, numb_pockets, size, color, length_sleeves, length_shirt, collar, hood, code, price, name);
    }
}
```

The reason why I don't just extend clothing with all the variables is because I don't want to state if or not 'Upper_wear' has 'Shoe_laces' which is a variable in 'Shoes'. Yet, I want to gather all parent classes into one because when I go to the run class. In the for loop, I want to list out the prices of every item of Clothing and not just of a parent class. I feel that I am limited to only iterating through one parent class at a time such as what I currently have:

```
public class Run
{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Shoes Tennis_shoes_01 = new Shoes("Canvas", 0, "yes", 10, "red and white", 0,0.5,2.5, 00001, 750.99,"Tenny shoey");
        Upper_wear T_shirt_01 = new Upper_wear("Cotton", 0, "no", 0, 14, "yellow", 14.5, 15, "v-neck", "no", 00002, 990.50, "Yel-ow");)

        Shoes[]In_Stock = {Tennis_shoes_01};
        Upper_wear[]In_Stock_upper = {};
        Lower_wear[]In_Stock_lower = {};


        System.out.println("Price");
        System.out.println("-------");
        for(Shoes x : In_Stock){
            System.out.println(x.get_name() + ": " +x.get_price());
        }
        for(Upper_wear x : In_Stock_upper){
            System.out.println(x.get_name() + ": " + x.get_price());
        }


    }
```

What I am wanting is something more like this:

```
public class Want_run
{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Clothing Tennis_shoes_01 = new Shoes("Canvas", 0, "yes", 10, "red and white", 0,0.5,2.5, 00001, 750.99,"Tenny shoey");
        //Not sure if this is possible to have a class that's different than the constructor but I am looking for it to come from clothing class with properties of Shoes.
        Clothing T_shirt_01 = new Upper_wear("Cotton", 0, "no", 0, 14, "yellow", 14.5, 15, "v-neck", "no", 00002, 990.50, "Yel-ow");
        //So I want all properties to be in clothing but the ones that the childeren don't have I want to be just blank.ex. Upper_wear is blank on the shoe_laces. 
        Clothing[]In_Stock = {Tennis_shoes_01, T_shirt_01};
        //I really want everything to be just in one list to iterate through but I can't currently do that with multiple parents of my knowledge.
        for(Clothing x : In_Stock){
            System.out.println(x.get_name() + ": " + x.get_price());
        }
        //this way I have only one for loop for every item,and for parents that don't have 'price' I am hoping would just not print.
    }
}
```

So I want clothing to have every attribute of 'Upper_wear', 'Lower_wear', and 'Shoes', but not the parents to have every attribute of Clothing. Such that the attributes that are specific to Shoes, I wish to be blank for the other two parents when it iterates through methods specific to Shoes. I'm not sure if what I am looking for is even possible to do. If you cannot understand what I am looking for, I am sorry for being confusing. Thank you for taking your time to read this and helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a classic application of polymorphism. You just need to clarify a few concepts.

Your grand parent will contain all the attributes that are common to all children, such as item ID, name, colour(s), price, etc. It should also contain common functions, such as a print() function which is what you require in your main.

All children (including parents) will introduce their specific attributes in their classes, such as hood/collar for uppers, and inner lining for jacket. They will also override (provide their own implementation of) functions they need to customize according to their needs. So, in your case, while the Clothing will have a print() function, each sub class will have its own implementation of it, in which it will print all its own properties such as number of zippers, shoelaces.

Finally, in your main, you will have a list of type Clothing, which will contain references to objects of all types you want. A parent can point to an object of a child type. For example,

```
Clothing c = new Jacket(...);
c.print();    // This will call the print() of class Jacket, not Clothing
```

I suggest reading up on dynamic polymorphism. [This link](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/runtime-compile-time-polymorphism/) contains a quick introduction and a nifty example.